# Usage of CONFIG_SYS_MAX_NAND_DEVICE macro in U-boot

Tags: u-boot

I could see following macro definitions in IMX53 evk board config file(mx53_evk.h).

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_NAND_MAX_CHIPS     8
#define CONFIG_SYS_MAX_NAND_DEVICE    1
```

The `CONFIG_SYS_NAND_MAX_CHIPS` macro value defines no.of NAND chips we have on the board, but what is the usage of `CONFIG_SYS_MAX_NAND_DEVICE` macro. can you help me to understand. U-boot(2009.08) is using for IMX53 evk board.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that you're using a release from Freescale with patches for i.MX rather than the stock v2009.08 release.  Aside from suggesting that you switch to mainline (i.MX5 is very well supported these days), I believe the answer here (based on a Freescale release I happen to have around) is that for that tree (and not mainline) you should set CONFIG_SYS_NAND_MAX_CHIPS to 8 (Freescale sets this to 8 everywhere) and CONFIG_SYS_MAX_NAND_DEVICE to the number that you have.  This appears to be related to making a distinction in how the NAND chip itself works that is no longer done.

Comment: If we define CONFIG_SYS_MAX_NAND_DEVICE as 1 , then it will treat all NAND chips as single device.

Comment: Right.  Again, in this particular BSP Freescale seems to have done some things that aren't quite in-line with how the rest of the codebase was at the time nor is today.  The distinction to make is on, well, how many physical NAND devices you're populating the device with, not the internal makeup of the NAND package.  Baring any very complex configurations you're attempting to make anyhow.